# How to integrate amazon s3 api into my website

Tags: node.js

I want to know how to implement amazon s3 api into my website so that I can upload files to my bucket. I tried searching online and going through the api documentation but to no avail. Please help

Comment: first link on google https://www.npmjs.com/package/s3

Answer (score 1):

Depends what language you are using. At work we use Amazon S3 and Route53 and there is a nuget package for dotnet core https://www.nuget.org/packages/AWSSDK.S3 For nodejs you may be looking for https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-node-js/